# Call bash script in Java program with export variables

Tags: java, bash, unix

I need to call a bash script in java class . Before calling the bash script , few variables need to be exported. So when bash script is executed. It's should get the required exported values.

class Javapgm {

public static void main(String [] args){

//export VAR=10

//Call bash script script.bash so that it can use this VAR

}

}

Answer (score 3):

To execute a bash script, use [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).
To set environment variables, call [`environment()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#environment--).

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh", "-c", "script.bash");
pb.inheritIO();
pb.environment().put("VAR", "10");
Process p = pb.start();
p.waitFor();
```